# footer button with jQuery mobile 1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I've converted my app to the new jQuery mobile 1.4.
But now, there is a small border at my footer button on the left side. 
How can I remove this border?

My code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">    

    <div data-role="content">
    </div>

    <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#test" data-transition="fade" data-icon="edit">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rTFmR/1/

Comment: Please check my update with another fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

Another fix, override `.ui-block-a`'s `margin-left`, and keep `data-role="nabvar"` attribute. Because this issue occurs only when using *one* navbar button.

```
li.ui-block-a {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

---

Navbar widget is still *not* 100% ready and needs to be re-factored. Anyway, to fix your problem, remove `data-role="navbar"` and replace it with `class="ui-navbar"`.

Also, not that `data-role="button"` will be removed on jQuery Mobile 1.5. You need to add classes manually to *anchor* tag. `ui-btn` class converts any anchor into a button. For icons and there positions, `ui-icon-edit` and `ui-btn-icon-top` respectively.

```
<div class="ui-navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#test" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-top ui-icon-edit" data-transition="fade">Test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qdUQF/)**